# Not able to reference Airpush Airpush; in my class

Tags: android, airpush

I want to integrate air-push notification ads in my app, I followed their tutorial from: http://manage.airpush.com/docs/?title=Android_SDK_6.0_Documentation#Step_1_-_Adding_the_JAR

However it does not seem to work for me, I am getting an error at

```
 Airpush airpush;
```

when I try to reference it in the class file, I have referenced the jar correctly of which I am attaching a screen shot. http://img856.imageshack.us/img856/985/jrkn.jpg

Answer (score 1):

All I know Airpush class is removed, now they are using different class in their SDK. please contact Airpush support.

Comment: Thier support is too slow, I did now they ask me to include a different SDK. Haah, I better go with tap for tap

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using old documentation use the links below:

For AirSDK for Google play store version
http://manage.airpush.com/docs/index.php?title=AirSDK_1.0_for_Play_Store_Documentation

For AirSDK universal version
http://manage.airpush.com/docs/index.php?title=AirSDK_1.0_Universal_Documentation

Hope this helps:

Comment: No, please refer to the screenshot provided. I have followed the steps in the first link you provided.